# Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) - PostgreSQL on remote server

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to set up a new postgresql database with a remote server (Ubuntu) a Django project for the last 2 days but keep having this same issue over and over again. What should I do?

Here's the error output that I'm getting when I try to make migrations to the database:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\loicq\desktop\coding\uvergo\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection
refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

And the code in my settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'loicq',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I've run the following to but still getting the error:

```
sudo -i -u root
```

```
echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
```

```
echo 'host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5' >> /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
```

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

And I also created a new Server in PgAdmin with the same Ip Adress as my Droplet on Digital Ocean but still.

Please let me know if you have anything, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Okay so I found the solution**:

I replaced this code in my settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'loicq',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

With this:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://YOURUSER:YOURPASSWORD@YOURHOST:5432/YOURDATABASENAME')}
```

Installed dj-database-url with pip:

```
pip install dj_database_url
```

And now it work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Postgres uses PORT **5432** as standard.
I would recommend to updated your settings.py this way:

```
   DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
          'NAME': 'dbname',
          'USER': 'postgres',
          'PASSWORD': 'password',
          'HOST': 'localhost',
          'PORT': '5432',
           }

     }
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it’s going to work but I’m going to give it a try. Should I add the _psycopg2 extension after backends.postrgesql or it is not necessary?